# Get current route inside Controller Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have several routes in web.php:

```
Route::get('/','PagesController@index');

Route::get('/contact','PagesController@contact');
```

and so on...

I need to get in my PagesController the current 'module' (index, contact or smth else).

The Controller's code:

```
   class PagesController extends Controller
   {
    public function index()
    {
       $menu = new Menu();

       $links = $menu->getMenu();

       //$header=url()->current(); // returns the full url, e.g. http://test.com/
       //$header=Route::current(); // error: Class Route not found

       return view("index",['links'=>$links,'header'=>$header]);
    }
}
```

For example, $header should be equal to "/" inside `PagesController@index` and `$header = "contact"` inside `PagesController@contact`.

I need the universal solution for all the modules I'll have in future.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you calling the route a module? Is `Route::current()` what you're looking for?

Comment: I've updated my question to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not had a chance to test this, however you should be able to achieve this with the following:

```
Route::get('/{page?}', function($page = 'index') {
    return app('App\Http\Controllers\PageController')->{$page}($page);
});
```

Basically, this is setting a route to have an optional `$page` variable. If no page name is passed (e.g. `contact`), we default to `index`.

We finally use the `app()` helper to call the `PageController` and then use the `->{$page}()` syntax to call a dynamic controller method (In the default case `index`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got that, but I still can’t completely understand how to create $module variable in PagesController which will store the current module?

Comment: Please update the question with your controller model, I'll update my answer afterwards.

Comment: @Viktor I've updated my answer, you will need to pass `$page` as an argument like `->{$page}($page)`. Then, in your controller, always expect a variable e.g. `public function contact($header)`.

Comment: @Viktor However, if each `page` has its own method/function. you can just pass to the view like ` return view("index",['links' => $links, 'header' =>  ' contact']);`